# Outlook does not understand my ical file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, outlook, icalendar

I am trying to create an iCalendar feed on my MVC3 website that users can subscribe to. I successfully created the ical file using the DDay.ical library. When I download the the ical file from the website and open it with outlook it opens fine. However, when I try to subscribe to it with outlook by right clicking on the list of calendars and selecting

> Add calendar => From internet...

and entering the url to the ical file, it tells me the file is not a valid internet calendar file.

What is going on here? Can anyone help me with this please?

My ical file is displayed below:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:mywebsite
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20120907T120000
DTSTAMP:20120906T110251
DTSTART:20120907T080000
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:Confirmed
SUMMARY:Nanosurf easyScan 2 STM
UID:170ee5f7-0b22-4b64-adae-dfaff0277e96
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20120810T120000
DTSTAMP:20120906T110251
DTSTART:20120810T090000
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:Confirmed
SUMMARY:Nanosurf easyScan 2 STM
UID:2a7e4445-1fe5-4224-b4b3-61e33785e181
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20120814T130000
DTSTAMP:20120906T110251
DTSTART:20120814T090000
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:Confirmed
SUMMARY:Nanosurf easyScan 2 STM
UID:ee1535a6-e971-4a92-a06a-5d10d414cf07
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a space behind every line.

http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/

Comment: I couldn't see that there was a space behind every line though. However, when I checked the ics file it showed me that there were three weird characters at the front of the file. Something to do with the utf-8 encoding. I fixed that and the file validates, but the file still won't be accepted by Outlook as an internet calendar!

Is it possible that it somehow makes a differences that is written to disk first? Unfortunately I cannot enter the URL in the validation tool because it only runs locally, and I can't deploy it to the webserver yet..

Comment: jkokorian - Did you find an answer to this, i'm having the exact same issue. An .ics loads if saved, but wont load from a webpage feed

Comment: @GordonCopestake Did you check your feed using the test url from my answer?

Comment: My problem was user error... Whilst my webpage rendered perfectly my outlook client wasn't able to logon to the webapp. Added anonymous exception to my system.config and all is well. /slaps forehead